# how to use socket io many times in the same app(vue js node js)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, notifications, dashboard

I have a big app which containes a real time chat and real time notification and real dashboard .
i'm new to socket io so can someone explain to me how the implmentaion will be?

Answer (score 1):

You could run socket.io server on many port in different files (so that it become easy to operate) and then connect to that port only